Can undefine a symbol defined by ffi.cdef in Luajit?
Well, I've been reading Luajit ffi's documents for several days and knew how to use it basically.
Define symbols(ffi.cdef(xxx)),
then load libraries(a = ffi.load(xxx)),
and simply call them(a.xxx(...)).
All amazed e a lot.
But there's one thing confusing me is that ffi.cdef is a "static"(sorry I couldn't find words to describe it, so treat it as a Java static method...) function, which means all I have defined will be used to process of indexing symbols for all libraries.
Let's show an example.
Tow C source files a.c and b.c
In a.c:
void func(int p1){}

In b.c:
void func(int p1, int p2){}

Build them separately to liba.so and libb.so
In lua:
ffi.cdef "void func(int)"
local lib = ffi.load("a")
lib.func(1) -- Succeeded

ffi.cdef "void func(int,int)"
lib = ffi.load("b")
lib.func(1,2) -- Failed: wrong number of  arguments for function call

I tried to set lib = nil and call collectgargarbage("collect") before loading libb.so because I read Luajit keeps caches of every symbols with its parameters and return type, until it has no reference.
But failed...
And many other tries also didn't work.
Help!

BTW, the number of user types you can define using ffi.cdef is very limited (only a few hundreds), after reaching this limit you can neither replace old nor add new.  So, LJ is not suitable for massive creation of new types in runtime.

At the time of writing this, LuaJIT's ffi.cdef ignores redeclarations. Source: https://github.com/LuaJIT/LuaJIT/issues/28.
